# Pymodbus updating_server abnormal operation

Tags: master-slave, rs485, pymodbus

I used pymodbus's updating_server to simulate the modbus slave. The modbus network configuration is master(arduino) and 2 slaves, the one with ID 0x01 is the inverter controller and the one with ID 0x02 is the simulator implemented with updating_server. The problem is that MASTER makes data requests to ID 01 and 02, but UPDATING_SERVER fails to deliver data frequently. I am attaching updating_server_01.py and a related file, server_async.py.

updating_server_01.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Pymodbus asynchronous Server Example.

An example of a multi threaded asynchronous server.

usage: server_async.py [-h] [--comm {tcp,udp,serial,tls}]
                       [--framer {ascii,binary,rtu,socket,tls}]
                       [--log {critical,error,warning,info,debug}]
                       [--port PORT] [--store {sequential,sparse,factory,none}]
                       [--slaves SLAVES]

Command line options for examples

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --comm {tcp,udp,serial,tls}
                        "serial", "tcp", "udp" or "tls"
  --framer {ascii,binary,rtu,socket,tls}
                        "ascii", "binary", "rtu", "socket" or "tls"
  --log {critical,error,warning,info,debug}
                        "critical", "error", "warning", "info" or "debug"
  --port PORT           the port to use
  --store {sequential,sparse,factory,none}
                        "sequential", "sparse", "factory" or "none"
  --slaves SLAVES       number of slaves to respond to

The corresponding client can be started as:
    python3 client_sync.py
"""
import asyncio
import logging

from helper import get_commandline
from server_async import run_async_server, setup_server
from pymodbus.datastore import (
    ModbusSequentialDataBlock,
    ModbusServerContext,
    ModbusSlaveContext,
)

global count_t
count_t = 1794
_logger = logging.getLogger()


async def updating_task(context):
    """Run every so often,

    and updates live DO of the context. It should be noted
    that there is a lrace condition for the update.
    """
    while True:
        global count_t
        global DO
        _logger.debug("updating the context")
        register = 3
        slave_id = 0x02
        address = 0x10
        DO_list = context[slave_id].getValues(register, address, count=1)
        # DO = [v + 1 for v in DO]  # increment by 1.
        if count_t < 1800:
            DO = 500
        elif count_t >=1800 and count_t < 3600:
            DO = int((5/1800*count_t)*100)
        elif count_t >=3600 and count_t < 7200:
            DO = 10*100
        elif count_t >= 7200 and count_t < 9000:
            DO = int((-5/1800*count_t +30)*100)
        elif count_t >= 9000:
            DO = 500
        DO_list = [DO for v in DO_list]
        txt = f"new DO: {str(DO_list)}"
        # _logger.debug(txt)
        context[slave_id].setValues(register, address, DO_list)
        print(txt+str(count_t))
        count_t=count_t+5
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


def setup_updating_server(args):
    """Run server setup."""
    # The datastores only respond to the addresses that are initialized
    # If you initialize a DataBlock to addresses of 0x00 to 0xFF, a request to
    # 0x100 will respond with an invalid address exception.
    # This is because many devices exhibit this kind of behavior (but not all)

    # Continuing, use a sequential block without gaps.
    datablock = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0x00, [17] * 100)
    context = ModbusSlaveContext(
        di=datablock, co=datablock, hr=datablock, ir=datablock, unit=1
    )
    args.context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=context, single=True)
    return setup_server(args)

async def run_updating_server(args):
    """Start updater task and async server."""
    asyncio.create_task(updating_task(args.context))
    await run_async_server(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd_args = get_commandline(
        server=True,
        description="Run asynchronous server.",
    )
    run_args = setup_updating_server(cmd_args)
    asyncio.run(run_updating_server(run_args), debug=True)
```

server_async.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Pymodbus asynchronous Server Example.

An example of a multi threaded asynchronous server.

usage: server_async.py [-h] [--comm {tcp,udp,serial,tls}]
                       [--framer {ascii,binary,rtu,socket,tls}]
                       [--log {critical,error,warning,info,debug}]
                       [--port PORT] [--store {sequential,sparse,factory,none}]
                       [--slaves SLAVES]

Command line options for examples

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --comm {tcp,udp,serial,tls}
                        "serial", "tcp", "udp" or "tls"
  --framer {ascii,binary,rtu,socket,tls}
                        "ascii", "binary", "rtu", "socket" or "tls"
  --log {critical,error,warning,info,debug}
                        "critical", "error", "warning", "info" or "debug"
  --port PORT           the port to use
  --store {sequential,sparse,factory,none}
                        "sequential", "sparse", "factory" or "none"
  --slaves SLAVES       number of slaves to respond to

The corresponding client can be started as:
    python3 client_sync.py
"""
import asyncio
import logging
import os

from helper import get_commandline
from pymodbus.datastore import (
    ModbusSequentialDataBlock,
    ModbusServerContext,
    ModbusSlaveContext,
    ModbusSparseDataBlock,
)
from pymodbus.device import ModbusDeviceIdentification

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# import the various client implementations
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from pymodbus.server import (
    StartAsyncSerialServer,
    StartAsyncTcpServer,
    StartAsyncTlsServer,
    StartAsyncUdpServer,
)
from pymodbus.version import version


_logger = logging.getLogger()


def setup_server(args):
    """Run server setup."""
    # The datastores only respond to the addresses that are initialized
    # If you initialize a DataBlock to addresses of 0x00 to 0xFF, a request to
    # 0x100 will respond with an invalid address exception.
    # This is because many devices exhibit this kind of behavior (but not all)
    _logger.info("### Create datastore")
    if args.store == "sequential":
        # Continuing, use a sequential block without gaps.
        datablock = ModbusSequentialDataBlock(0x00, [10] * 100)
    elif args.store == "sparse":
        # Continuing, or use a sparse DataBlock which can have gaps
        datablock = ModbusSparseDataBlock({0x00: 0, 0x05: 1})
    elif args.store == "factory":
        # Alternately, use the factory methods to initialize the DataBlocks
        # or simply do not pass them to have them initialized to 0x00 on the
        # full address range::
        datablock = ModbusSequentialDataBlock.create()

    if args.slaves:
        # The server then makes use of a server context that allows the server
        # to respond with different slave contexts for different unit ids.
        # By default it will return the same context for every unit id supplied
        # (broadcast mode).
        # However, this can be overloaded by setting the single flag to False and
        # then supplying a dictionary of unit id to context mapping::
        #
        # The slave context can also be initialized in zero_mode which means
        # that a request to address(0-7) will map to the address (0-7).
        # The default is False which is based on section 4.4 of the
        # specification, so address(0-7) will map to (1-8)::
        context = {
            # 0x01: ModbusSlaveContext(
            #     di=datablock,
            #     co=datablock,
            #     hr=datablock,
            #     ir=datablock,
            # ),
            0x02: ModbusSlaveContext(
                di=datablock,
                co=datablock,
                hr=datablock,
                ir=datablock,
            ),
            # 0x03: ModbusSlaveContext(
            #     di=datablock, co=datablock, hr=datablock, ir=datablock, zero_mode=True
            # ),
        }
        single = False
    else:
        context = ModbusSlaveContext(
            di=datablock, co=datablock, hr=datablock, ir=datablock, unit=1
        )
        single = True

    # Build data storage
    args.context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=context, single=single)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    # initialize the server information
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    # If you don"t set this or any fields, they are defaulted to empty strings.
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    args.identity = ModbusDeviceIdentification(
        info_name={
            "VendorName": "Pymodbus",
            "ProductCode": "PM",
            "VendorUrl": "https://github.com/riptideio/pymodbus/",
            "ProductName": "Pymodbus Server",
            "ModelName": "Pymodbus Server",
            "MajorMinorRevision": version.short(),
        }
    )
    return args


async def run_async_server(args):
    """Run server."""
    txt = f"### start ASYNC server, listening on {args.port} - {args.comm}"
    _logger.info(txt)
    if args.comm == "tcp":
        address = ("169.254.209.15", args.port) if args.port else None
        server = await StartAsyncTcpServer(
            context=args.context,  # Data storage
            identity=args.identity,  # server identify
            # TBD host=
            # TBD port=
            address=address,  # listen address
            # custom_functions=[],  # allow custom handling
            framer=args.framer,  # The framer strategy to use
            # handler=None,  # handler for each session
            allow_reuse_address=True,  # allow the reuse of an address
            # ignore_missing_slaves=True,  # ignore request to a missing slave
            # broadcast_enable=False,  # treat unit_id 0 as broadcast address,
            # timeout=1,  # waiting time for request to complete
            # TBD strict=True,  # use strict timing, t1.5 for Modbus RTU
            # defer_start=False,  # Only define server do not activate
        )
    elif args.comm == "udp":
        address = ("127.0.0.1", args.port) if args.port else None
        server = await StartAsyncUdpServer(
            context=args.context,  # Data storage
            identity=args.identity,  # server identify
            address=address,  # listen address
            # custom_functions=[],  # allow custom handling
            framer=args.framer,  # The framer strategy to use
            # handler=None,  # handler for each session
            # TBD allow_reuse_address=True,  # allow the reuse of an address
            # ignore_missing_slaves=True,  # ignore request to a missing slave
            # broadcast_enable=False,  # treat unit_id 0 as broadcast address,
            # timeout=1,  # waiting time for request to complete
            # TBD strict=True,  # use strict timing, t1.5 for Modbus RTU
            # defer_start=False,  # Only define server do not activate
        )
    elif args.comm == "serial":
        # socat -d -d PTY,link=/tmp/ptyp0,raw,echo=0,ispeed=9600
        #             PTY,link=/tmp/ttyp0,raw,echo=0,ospeed=9600
        server = await StartAsyncSerialServer(
            context=args.context,  # Data storage
            identity=args.identity,  # server identify
            timeout=1,  # waiting time for request to complete
            port=args.port,  # serial port
            custom_functions=[],  # allow custom handling
            framer=args.framer,  # The framer strategy to use
            handler=None,  # handler for each session
            stopbits=1,  # The number of stop bits to use
            bytesize=8,  # The bytesize of the serial messages
            parity="N",  # Which kind of parity to use
            baudrate=9600,  # The baud rate to use for the serial device
            handle_local_echo=False,  # Handle local echo of the USB-to-RS485 adaptor
            ignore_missing_slaves=False,  # ignore request to a missing slave
            broadcast_enable=False,  # treat unit_id 0 as broadcast address,
            strict=True,  # use strict timing, t1.5 for Modbus RTU
            defer_start=False,  # Only define server do not activate
        )
    elif args.comm == "tls":
        address = ("", args.port) if args.port else None
        cwd = os.getcwd().split("/")[-1]
        if cwd == "examples":
            path = "."
        elif cwd == "test":
            path = "../examples"
        else:
            path = "examples"
        server = await StartAsyncTlsServer(
            context=args.context,  # Data storage
            host="localhost",  # define tcp address where to connect to.
            # port=port,  # on which port
            identity=args.identity,  # server identify
            # custom_functions=[],  # allow custom handling
            address=address,  # listen address
            framer=args.framer,  # The framer strategy to use
            # handler=None,  # handler for each session
            allow_reuse_address=True,  # allow the reuse of an address
            certfile=f"{path}/certificates/pymodbus.crt",  # The cert file path for TLS (used if sslctx is None)
            # sslctx=sslctx,  # The SSLContext to use for TLS (default None and auto create)
            keyfile=f"{path}/certificates/pymodbus.key",  # The key file path for TLS (used if sslctx is None)
            # password="none",  # The password for for decrypting the private key file
            # reqclicert=False,  # Force the sever request client"s certificate
            # ignore_missing_slaves=True,  # ignore request to a missing slave
            # broadcast_enable=False,  # treat unit_id 0 as broadcast address,
            # timeout=1,  # waiting time for request to complete
            # TBD strict=True,  # use strict timing, t1.5 for Modbus RTU
            defer_start=False,  # Only define server do not activate
        )
    return server


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cmd_args = get_commandline(
        server=True,
        description="Run asynchronous server.",
    )
    run_args = setup_server(cmd_args)
    asyncio.run(run_async_server(run_args), debug=True)
```

When I implemented updating_server, I wrote "python updating_server_01.py --comm serial --port com6 --slaves 1" in the cmd window.

When I analyze the packets, sometimes the updating_server does not respond when the arduino requests "02 03 00 10 00 01 85 fc".

Any help would be appreciated.

The arduino requests data from both ID 01 and ID 02, and ID 01 normally operated, but ID 02 fails to deliver the data frequently. Other times, it passes the data just fine.